# How to compare two non-ASCII strings

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.7, ascii

I want to compare `Technical Diploma (±12 years)` with the same string present in the browser. I am running a webdriver test in Python where it fetches `Technical Diploma (±12 years)` from a db and tries to compare with a string present in the browser. I am getting this error when I try to compare

> UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

How do I compare these non-ASCII strings in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of your strings is not a unicode value, but a bytestring. You want to convert that to unicode by decoding it first:

```
'Non-ASCII value containing UTF8: \xc2\xb1'.decode('utf8')
```

but you will have to figure out what encoding the bytestring is in in the first place.

If you have defined a source file encoding and you are defining the string as a literal in your code, make sure you define it as a Unicode literal by prefixing the string with a `u''`:

```
u'Technical Diploma (±12 years)'
```

I strongly recommend you read up on the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) before you proceed, however.

Answer (score 1):

Python is telling you the problem: Convert to UTF-8 first.

Example:

```
>>> u1='Technical Diploma (±12 years)'
>>> u2=u'Technical Diploma (±12 years)'
>>> u1==u2
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
False
>>> u1.decode('utf-8')==u2
True
>>>
```